# How to update a bar chart with accompanying text in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm creating a bar chart as part of a bigger data visualization in d3. I want to be able to change the data in one part of the visualization and all the charts will be updated. A simplified version of the chart is as follows.

```
var dataset = [1, 3, 5, 3, 3];

...
var svg = d3.select("body #container").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var g = svg.append("g");
...
```

I create other charts like a map, circle etc with this svg element. The bar chart is implemented like this.

```
 function bars(dataset) {
      var barChart = g.selectAll("rect.bar")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter();

      barChart.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 30 + 100; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return (height - 130) - d * 4;})
        .attr("width", 25)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d * 4; });


       barChart.append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 30 + 103; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return (height - 130) - d/10 - 5;})
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "10px")
        .attr("fill", "darkgray"); 
}
```

Now this renders the bar chart fine but there is a function

```
...
.on("click", function() {
   ...
   var newdata = [5, 2, 6, 2, 4]; // new values
   g.selectAll("rect.bar").remove();  // This removes the bars
   g.selectAll("text").remove();    // Problem here: All texts are removed
   bars(newdata);
}
```

I have tried to transition the bar chart with new values with the .remove() function. This works for the bar rectangles because there are no othe bar charts but when I tried to remove the value labels like shown above all the other text elements were also removed. Is there a way to only update the text associated with the bars?

Comment: why are you removing elements with force? if you bind the data and use the enter, update, exit pattern you shouldn't need to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried applying a class to the text and only selecting those ones for removal?
e.g.

```
barChart.append("text")
  .attr('class','label')
  .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

then

```
g.selectAll(".label").remove();
```

Incidentally, if not all of the elements are being deleted between updates, then instead of removing all of the elements, have you considered using `enter()` and [`exit()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#exit) to bind the new data to the existing elements and only remove the elements that are changing?

**EDIT** Like this:

```
function bars(dataset) {
  var bar = g.selectAll(".bar").data(dataset);

  bar.exit().remove();

  bar.enter().append("rect").attr("class", "bar");

  bar
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 30 + 100; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (height - 130) - d * 4;})
    .attr("width", 25)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d * 4; });

  var label = g.selectAll(".label").data(dataset);

  label.exit().remove();

  label.enter().append("text").attr("class", "label");

  label
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 30 + 103; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (height - 130) - d/10 - 5;})
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "10px")
    .attr("fill", "darkgray"); 
}
```

Comment: thanks applying a separate class to the text works. but seems like exit() is the recommended way. can you show how that might be achieved here? i did barChart().exit().remove() at the end of the code but it doesn't work.